# JPA Criteria Query - Set ehcache region name?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria, jpa-criteria

I could enable query caching for jpa criteria using below -

```
javax.persistence.Query regularQuery = em.createQuery(query);
regularQuery.setHint("org.hibernate.cacheable", true);
```

I also want to specify the cache name for this query, i tried below but its not working.

```
regularQuery.setHint("org.hibernate.cache.region", "xcain4");
```

How can I provide the cache name.. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```java
import org.hibernate.jpa.QueryHints;

// ...

javax.persistence.Query regularQuery = em.createQuery(query);
regularQuery.setHint(QueryHints.HINT_CACHEABLE, true);
regularQuery.setHint(QueryHints.HINT_CACHE_REGION, "xcain4");
```

See [this part](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#caching-query-region) of the hibernate documentation.

Comment: `org.hibernate.jpa.QueryHints` works like blaze. +1 Accepted.